# How to create .zshrc in Mac home directory?

Tags: macos, flutter

I have started using Mac for the first time and I am trying to set up flutter. One of the steps is to add path in file `.zshrc`. For this I have to first create this file. In Windows, whenever I had to create file, I used Git Bash and use `touch <filename>` in any directory and the file was created. Some websites mention that touch works in Mac terminal also.

How to create this file in home directory? I tried going to the home directory using `cd ~` and then `touch .zshrc` and `touch ~/.zshrc` but they don't seem to work. I also tried to save file with this extension using `TextEdit` but doesn't work either. I have checked Show all filename extensions in Finder > Preferences > Advanced.

So what is the way to create this file in home directory either using Finder or terminal?

Comment: does this helps you -->https://newbedev.com/where-is-the-zshrc-file-on-mac

Comment: The link also mentions to create this file like this: `touch ~/.zshrc` but it is not working in my case, to see the files, I am using `ls` command but it doesn't show this file after using the touch command.

Comment: Try `ls -a ~` to see dot files.

Comment: By the way, `cd ~` is ugly and pointless. Just use `cd` since it goes to your login directory by default and is shorter.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes I saw a video some time ago and realized that one needs to press `Command + Shift + .` to see dot files.